# What type of exception should be thrown in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, exception, throw

What type of object should be thrown in JavaScript?

I see a lot of [examples](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_throw.asp) which throw a plain old `string` and there seems to be a semi-standard [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/error) type. Should I prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Error` object and specific error objects such as `TypeError` are fully standardized in the ECMAScript specification. There are, however, common non-standard properties of these objects available in most browsers.

You can throw whatever you like, so long as your error handling code knows what to do with the objects you throw, but there are advantages to using `Error` objects:

- Consistency with handling errors thrown by native code, such as having a `message` property, so you don't have to write different code to handle native errors and your own errors;
- `Error` objects in Mozilla and other browsers have very useful non-standard properties, such as `fileName`, `lineNumber` and [`stack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack). You only get these on `Error` objects and they can be very useful for debugging.